# The unparsed-text() function doesn't work when Saxon 11 is run from ANT

Tags: java, xslt, ant, saxon

I'm using **Saxon 11** from **ANT**. XSLT transformation works, except that the **unparsed-text()** function triggers a fatal error.
Error message:

```
Resolver for unparsed-text() returned non-StreamSource;
```

Software: SaxonEE11-3J, Ant 1.10.3, Java openjdk 1.8.0.191 win64, Windows 10 Pro

Ant code:

```
<path id="xslt.saxonEE.classpath">
    <fileset dir="D:/SaxonEE11-3J">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="target-test">
    <xslt in="C:/input.xml" style="D:/test.xsl" out="C:/test.xml" force="true" processor="trax">
        <classpath refid="xslt.saxonEE.classpath"/>
        <factory name="com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseTransformerFactory">
            <attribute name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/ignoreSAXSourceParser" value="true"/>
            <!--<attribute name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/unparsedTextURIResolverClass" value="net.sf.saxon.lib.StandardUnparsedTextResolver"/>-->
        </factory>
    </xslt>
</target>
```

Comment: Unfortunately to accommodate all the flexibility of unparsed-text, json-doc, as well as text and binary file access, Saxon has been moving further and further away from the old XSLT-1.0 based JAXP interfaces assumed by Ant. You can probably do something by setting the right factory attributes, but in the end it might be simpler to invoke Saxon from Ant as a Java application rather than as a JAXP Transformer, if you want to use XSLT 2.0/3.0 extensions.

Comment: Just FYI: we've tried to run Saxon as a <java> task.
It works, but when running multiple transformations during the same process - performance is reduced significantly.
Like it starts the whole JVM and Saxon environment again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mike observes, the XSLT 1.0 based interfaces are getting a bit long in the tooth. However, I think it would probably be possible to support this request. I've opened [bug 5582](https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5582) to track it.